# Vue + Firebase: Users being created but logged in under other users accounts

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm having a pretty weird issue in Firebase where if I create a new user with the same password as a previous user that new user is being created with the correct information but is being logged in under a previous users account and is displayed all that users previous information.

I log out and then I sign in with the new users info and only then am I displayed the correct information. I was also having an issue of the new user overwriting the previous users path in Firebase if I was using the same password but I can't seem to recreate that.

My code to create a new user is as follows

```js
createNewUser () {

    // Create a new user with email and password.

    var email = this.newUserEmail;
    var password = this.newUserPassword; 

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // ...
    }).then(() => {

      firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
         database.ref('/users/' + user.uid).set({
             name: this.newUserName,
             email: this.newUserEmail,
             isRetailer: false,
             isAdmin: false
         });
      });  
    });

    // Push to home 

    router.push({ path: '/' });

    }
  }
}
```

The newly created user is then taken to the main home page where the following code runs in the `created() {}` method

```js
// Checks for a user and dispatches an action changing isAuthed state to true. 
firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  console.log(store.state.authentication);
  console.log(user);
  store.dispatch('checkUser', user);
})
```

Lastly, this dispatches an action which runs the following

```js
 checkUser (context, user) {

    if (user.uid) {

    context.commit('authUser', user);

    // checkUser runs once when the app is initialized. 

    // Gets value of the user's isRetailer property from firebase. 

    firebase.database()
        .ref('/users/' + user.uid + '/isRetailer/')
        .once('value').then(snapshot => context.commit('isRetailer', {
            value: snapshot.val()
        }));

        // Gets name of the current user from Firebase and will eventually store that in Vuex state.

        firebase.database()
            .ref('/users/' + user.uid + '/name/')
            .once('value').then(snapshot => context.commit('getDisplayName', {
                name: snapshot.val()
            }));
        } else {
            console.log('No user currently logged in');
        }
    },
```

So essentially I am doing the following

1. Creating a new user with Firebase.
2. Persisting that user with to Firebase database.
3. Updating Vuex state based on some data I get from Firebase.

When I just went to create a new user with a completely new password, nothing happens and I get the following in the console.

[image]

HOWEVER, when I create another new user using a password that has been previously created, it logs me in but under the information of the last user (the one that was created with a new password). The user created with the new password, however, is not stored in Firebase.

It's really a bizzare issue I'm having and I'm really not sure what is causing it. The uid error is the only error I get in the console. Can I not use a promise when creating the user? I added this in because users weren't being added to firebase because I wasn't able to grab the user after the account was created.

Could really use another set of eyes on this one.

**UPDATE:** When trying to sign in with my info it seems my info is then overwritten in firebase by another users information. I am then also shown all that users information in the app. Then whenever I try and login with my email / password I am logged in as John Steve from now on.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Cannot read property 'uid' of null` is because firebase can return null for current user while initializing please see [manage-users guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users.)

And second problem I think that is due to you're changin path to home before firebase has finish to save user (remember that this task is asynchronous)

```
createNewUser () {

    // Create a new user with email and password.

    var email = this.newUserEmail;
    var password = this.newUserPassword; 

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // ...
    }).then(() => {

      firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
         database.ref('/users/' + user.uid).set({
             name: this.newUserName,
             email: this.newUserEmail,
             isRetailer: false,
             isAdmin: false
         }).then(()=>{
            // Push to home after user data has been saved
            router.push({ path: '/' });
        });
      });  
    });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I've removed `firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {})` and replaced it with `var user = firebaseAuth.currentUser;` in the first callback. I then remove the second callback with the `router.push()` method and move `router.push()` outside of the callback function. This seems to git rid of my error. I'll do some more testing here and see. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: For now I think this has solved my issue. Hopefully it has! Thanks for the lead :)